# override default DateTime format in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime, c#-2.0

I am working in an application built in .NET framework 2.0 but I am running it in .NET framework 4.0, with SQL server as a database.

when I try to take date as a input from Calendar controller (Webforms) its in the format dd/MM/yyyy and this application using Convert.ToDateTime() to parse this date and it throws exception.

so how can I resolve this problem and is there any way that DateTime class object store the date in specific format means I want to store date in dd/MM/yyyy format even when I copy this date object to another, then both object should have same format.

and sorry for My English :p

Comment: what is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: Which exact control are you using in webforms? I would expect any sensible one to expose a property which just gave you a DateTime. Note that `DateTime` (which is a struct, not a class) doesn't store a text representation at all.

Comment: Datetime doesn't store the date in any specific format. Odds are your format string is wrong in the `Convert`. Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: To = Convert.ToDateTime(Txtto.Text);

where Txtto is a Calendar. and Text property contains "12/31/2013"
and this is the exception
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean [this `Calendar` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should just use the [`SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`SelectedDates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddates%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property - let the control handle the conversions.

In general, you should avoid performing textual conversions unless you really need to. (This includes when you interact with the database - use parameterized SQL, and simply pass the `DateTime` values in the parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("29/01/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should avoid converting DateTime to string and back if you can help it.